Convert Mojo object to Python object
I am making a program for my assignment that primarily requires Python, and one of the modules is computationally intensive.
I was wondering if it would be possible to rewrite the module in mojo and export the main object that it creates into a Python-compatible object. The module requires Python imports but from what I’ve seen, you can import them with mojo just fine
Any suggestions?

just use numba instead -- details please. what specifically are you doing? code, no prose. [mre]
